Want community promotion ads
Just like BioSe community, CogSci SE community should have community promotion ads. These are created by website users, is relevant to site, is interest-based, is engaging, is knowledgiable, and is super fun. 
So i plea to start this practice in CogSci Meta too. 

Here I just copy paste a sample i created some years ago. i forgot the command prompt so i just copied and pasted. 



Do we have ads at all at the moment?

we once proposed a t-shirt. How does that idea go?

We don't have enough volunteers and patience support the bulk of the questions. I am still keen for a better onboarding process so questions at least refer to something rather than read like a thought bubble. Seems silly to advertise and gather more users when we are struggling to hold down the fort as it is...
